# Flash Player: general runtime error dialog will not pop up

Tags: windows-7, crash, flash-player

The problem I'm facing is this:
**The Flash Player fails to show the general runtime error**

I work with flash and use FlashDevelop to edit code. When I compile and run a project, if there is an error in my code that would generally pop up the runtime error window, it fails to show.

The only way I have right now to catch the errors is by compiling the project in Debug mode, which imposes a workflow that I dont like...

Also, when browsing internet, sometimes the flash plugin crashes, I assume is because of an un-handled error on a movie (in IE, the browser crashes as well, in FF I guess the plugin is sandboxed and only flash movies fail to show)

I'm using a new machine, with Windows 7 Home Premium 64b. 
IE is a 32b version.
I had Flash Player 10,3,181,26 debugger installed.
I just downgraded to 10,2,152,26 debugger version.

Any ideas?

Just wanted to clarify:
The issue is system wide specific, the flash player fails to display the runtime error window. the projector, activex or netscape based flash player fails to do so. It is not project specific.

Comment: Why don't you just use the debug mode? I do realize that is not your problem, but debugging will help you to a lot more information, like current variable content. Also, for your topic: Did you try installing a non-debugger version, just to compare? You don't debug anyway, you just look at uncaught runtime errors (which is, in itself, interesting as a developer ;D)

Comment: The issue i have is twofold, one one hand not having runtime errors displayed means that I can't do quick builds (to do a debug build is slower and most of the time I don't need the info) The other issue is that the player crashes when I'm browsing Internet and I have to restart the browser to get the player working again...

Comment: Please answer me here: Did you try to install a non-debugging version of Flash player to test?

Comment: The initial installation of the players where non-debugging, then upgraded to 10.3 debugger, downgraded to 10.2 debugger

Comment: Alright. Don't know what could be wrong then...

Comment: WHY DO YOU HAVE TO USE CAPS LOCK POST WIDE?!?!?

Comment: @Hello71: It is not post wide, just the edit. I use caps to make sure people read the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at your `mm.cfg` file located in your user dir `(c:\users\yourname`) and set:

```
SuppressDebuggerExceptionDialogs=0
```

Comment: :That was it! This had me going nuts for so long now, I was getting tired. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that this is an error-handling problem, meaning that the error is caught in the production version, while the debug version notifies on more errors.

It is impossible to remote-debug your project through this forum, but if you have try/catch statements, you might comment all of them out to make the error happen.

Comment: Tnxs for the reply. The issue is not related to a singular project, but rather to the player itself. Any Flash movie that errors don't pop up the runtime error window. And it seems like when I'm browsing internet, and a movie erros the (debug) player crashes instead of showing the window like it should...

Comment: What happens if you play a Flash movie offline via a player ?

Comment: Nothing crashes, but debug player behaves like the regular player, no runtime error window...

Comment: Maybe try it on another computer ?

Comment: Sorry but the issue is the **computer**...the fact that no debug Flash Player (ActiveX, Netscape based, or Projector) is throwing the runtime error window. It is not specific to a single project.

Comment: If the problem is in some of the operations done to the computer, then it will not show up on another computer. If the problem is the computer, then the solution may be uninstalling Flash and the browser via Revo, cleaning the registry and all installation folders, then reinstalling. If nothing works, then I can't help you, and will delete this answer.

Comment: I did uninstall the player with the tool provided by Adobe to do a downgrade from 10.3 to 10.2 Will try again with Revo...